# Xampp not showwing my projects in browser - htdocs folder

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, htdocs

I used windows 10 as the operating system and I installed xampp it's been a long time and it chews well, until yesterday after an error in mysql.

So I looked for solutions on the internet and I finally solved the error by copying the files from `C:\xampp\mysql\backup` to `C:\xampp\mysql\data`.

then the service mysql is well marketed even as Apache.

PhpMyadmin chews well without a problem. phpmyadmin page shows, but my code, will not show.

The problem is: my old projects exist in htdocs only display "`This page does not work`" and "`localhost`" in the title head, and nothing loads from my project files.

Note: I used codeigniter as a framework.
Note: I can navigate to a new project but for existing projects beyond that it no longer works.

Thank you P.al

Comment: enable erroro management, to get a concrete error with details.Every thing else is a guessing game

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply but do u know how to enable it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Directly like-
http://localhost/projects/form.html

Here your files should be inside C:\XAMPP\htdocs\Projects\yourfile.html

Answer (score -1):

The error in your picture appear an php script error
Edit php.ini for display error and notice in browser

```
display_errors = on
```

save the php.ini restart apache and reload page.

Comment: after checking php.ini, I found the display_errors option is on and despite that the problem is still there !

Comment: I added an image in the ad, you can view it "PICTURE2"

Comment: in php.ini find "error_log="C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log"" if is present open log file and post last lines. Otherwise insert a value on "error_log" restart pc and try.

Comment: as i can see the "logs" folder not exist in explorer

Comment: do i have to restart my pc ? u can check the PICTURE3 in the ad please

Comment: to make sure that the services restart correctly. have you read the contents of the log? what does it report?

Comment: It report this : [26-Jan-2020 19:31:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: this error occurs when an extension is enabled multiple times in php.ini (or in htaccess). check if "extension = php_intl.dll" (or similar) is not repeated, if present multiple times remove one line and restart services. however this is an warning message, after reload page post another log line.

Comment: unfortunately I can not solve the problem despite that I remove the double option of intl. the problem remains the same and the log file does not display anything new this time !!

Comment: i will restart my pc to reload the services completely

Comment: if you add this code in your first line of the index.php changes anything?`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: can u check the PICTURE4 please ! nothing changes !!

Comment: open the php tags before the code    `<?php `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>  then load the page

Comment: Nothing changes sir you can check the two last PICTURES, unfortunately i don't understand what the issue is !!!

Comment: try to change write permission on your project folder

Comment: just a question, after a mysql crash you have installed old version of xampp, codeigniter or new version updated?

Comment: after a mysql crash, i don't install anything, the version of xampp or codeigniter stills same, so what i did is to copying the files from C:\xampp\mysql\backup to C:\xampp\mysql\data. and after this the mysql service works fine. and about my project folder i didn't change anything inside it.

Comment: can you see the PICTURE6 please, after change the permissions and add a new user, nothing changes as well.

Comment: still gives you error if you add the "Everyone" user with all permissions enabled? try also to set  In /application/config/config.php the line
`$config['log_threshold'] = 4;` and read log in  application/logs   good luck :)

Comment: You are totally right, after this step the log displays problems with the database (PICTURE7) and actually when I try to access my tables in my database; errors are displayed (# 1932 - Table 'db.tblsessions' doesn't exist in engine) so happily I have already downloaded a copy of my database then after the restoration of the database; the project is working perfectly :D and that because of you sir and I thank you for your efforts and for your patience :) thanks a lot

Comment: i would be very grateful if u can help me to resolve the issue with mysql and the message error in phpmyadmin "#1932 - Table 'laravel6.products' doesn't exist in engine"

Comment: can u view the PICTURE8 please sir ! all my databases are broken like the picture